# How to query mmssms.db threads table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to query the threads table in mmssms.db, however, I get this exception when running my query:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: recipient_ids (code 1)
```

Here is the query that I am running.

```
Uri uri = Telephony.Threads.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] prj = new String[]{"_id", Telephony.ThreadsColumns.RECIPIENT_IDS};
    Cursor cur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, prj, "_id=?", new String[]{"10"}, null);
    if (cur != null) {
        System.out.println(DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cur));
        cur.close();
    }
```

This exception makes me think that I somehow have the Uri for the threads table wrong. Any idea what the correct way to query the threads table in mmssms.db?

I can verify that the threads table exists in mmssms.db by downloading the database to my computer and opening it in a DB browser.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the Uri. Here is the working code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
        final String[] prj = new String[]{"_id", "recipient_ids"};
        Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, prj, "_id=?", new String[]{thread_id}, null);
        if (cur != null) {
            System.out.println(DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cur));
            cur.close();
        }
```

The key difference here being: `content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true`